# How do I limit the suggested values in a property based on the value of another property?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a third interface/type where in the second prop values will only be based on the first prop value, and also this third interface will have a third prop. The reason I'm not extending the third prop from the first two interfaces is because I don't actually need it if I use it on some other stuff (and I dont think making it optional is right)

So here's what I did:

1. Create two interfaces A & B which have same properties but could have different values
2. Make a type where it's the union of the two interfaces
3. Make a new type containing the third property and mix it with the union of two types

Here's how I'm doing it

```
 const A_PROP1 = 'A_PROP1';
 const A_PROP2_VALUES = {
  type1: 'type1',
  type2: 'type2',
  type3: 'type3',
};

 const B_PROP1 = 'B_PROP1';
 const B_PROP2_VALUES = {
  type4: 'type4',
  type5: 'type5',
};

 interface A {
  prop1: typeof A_PROP1;
  prop2: keyof typeof A_PROP2_VALUES;
 }

 interface B {
  prop1: typeof B_PROP1;
  prop2: keyof typeof B_PROP2_VALUES;
 }

 type AB = A | B;

 type ABC = AB & {
  prop3: 'prop3_value';
 }
```

However when I do the following

```
const test: ABC = {
 prop3: 'prop3_value',
 prop1: A_PROP1,
 prop2: 'random entered value', //The suggestion for this one shows the combination of A_PROP2_VALUES and B_PROP2_VALUES 
}
```

The prop2 shows a warning where it combines `A_prop2_values` and `B_prop2_values` where I only want the `A_prop2_values`. How do I make this work?

Edit: I've updated the question as suggested. I'm beginning to think that this is an IDE problem and not from Typescript at all (I didn't check the Typescript log). By default I think it does combine the values showing you what the values could possibly be, and if you chose something that is wrong, it's going to give you a type errror.

This is solved, my sincere apologies

Comment: I was not able to reproduce; could you provide actual types instead of `A_propX_value`(s)? Generally, TS will compile this by inferring one or the other type of the union, as `prop1` would infer interface `A` here, it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] as mentioned in [ask]; ideally someone should be able to drop your code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Good luck!

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the help. It seems like I was just confused about how typescript shows suggestions. I have updated the question body and I think my issue is 'solved'. I'm really sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer here for folks like me who are lazy to read documentations; apparently when you do `typeof` to a direct constant (`const example = 'example'`) it gets inferred to as `'example'` and not as `'string'` which is going to be helpful when inferring multiple types.

When you're doing `typeof` for an object of constants, make sure that:

1. you have `as const` after declaration.
2. they don't contain `${var}_example` because otherwise they will be inferred to as 'strings' and not the one you wanted.